# Importing .doc file

Tags: python-3.x, import, doc

I know it has been asked a couple times, but none of those answers work for me that they suggested. My problem is that I cannot read/import the doc file without messing part of the string up.

I was close to the solution with the following code:

```py
with open('A.doc', errors='ignore') as f:
    text = f.read()
    print(text)
```

Comment: it seems you have encoding issue, make sure if the encoding is UTF-8 or something else.

Comment: @KevalDave how can I check that?

Comment: A `.doc` file is not a textfile. It is a very complex binary structure. You can read it as your code is doing, but interpreting what `read()` returns is not trivial, and there is no standard library module that will do it for you.